# Shop with discount system

Tags: php, cakephp, shopping-cart, cakephp-2.5

I am writing shop system in CakePHP Framework. I am stuck on writing flexible discount system.

I have Product model that can have many different attributes (ProductVariant Model and ProductAttribute model).

ProductVariant is the part where there is price specified, because I can have physical product with different price and e-product for download with different price (though content is the same). So from this model for consideration is type and price.

ProductAttributes are some properties of product - like category, language etc.
(attributes are defined in a key-value way and assigned to product)

Now I want operators to be able to add temporary discounts, discount codes etc. That would apply discounts on product basis depending on it's Variant and/or Attributes.

For instance - discount 20% for physical products in english language or -$5 for download products in german or english language.

I figured out that maybe I should create Models
- DiscountType (for percentage discount and just plain discount)
- DiscountScope (for discounting specific product ids and/or attributes and/or variants

But I am stuck here, wondering how to define those rule sets so the operator could add them easily (attributes and variants can be added by operator too, so there is infinite number of possibilities here, but accessible from DB of course).

And second part where I am stuck is applying discounts for order processing.
Should I use decorator pattern? If so I am clueless now how to apply it in Cake (or just in MVC).

If I can improve my question somehow or provide some parts of code that can help solve the problem please let me know.

Comment: use magento lots of options

Comment: And what if I have to write it myself? :)

Comment: better use tested platform

Comment: From the reasons I don't want to go through, I can't.

Comment: My plugin implements callbacks on the data through events https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-cart-plugin It triggers one for discounts already, you'll have to identify the items and apply the discounts accordingly. We have a client that implements discounts with complex rules through this and it works fine.